# make check boxes the same size

Tags: android, checkbox

One of my screen contains both check boxes predefined in the layout file and check boxes added programmatically. The problem is that they turned out different sizes.

The ones defined in layout file end up showing a bigger square box; when checked, the check mark is green (looks normal):

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:text="foo text"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:checked="false" />
```

The ones created in code, not only has a much smaller square box, but also has dimmer border; when checked, the check mark is blue (looks odd):

```
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        checkbox.setText(innerData.getType_description());
        checkbox.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
        somelinearlayout.addView(checkbox);
```

How can I modify the code, to have the same look and feel for all the check boxes?

Comment: don't do `wrap content` instead use `match parent`..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still the same.

Comment: you can use CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext(), your attri. , any style);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of creating your CheckBoxes programmatically, you inflate them instead. Probably a bit more expensive, but you get the correct LayoutParams from the parent ViewGroup and you can style the inflated CheckBox much more easily (since it is in an xml layout). Sample code below:

**"my_checkbox" xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</CheckBox>
```

**Activity layout**

```
// excerpt from the activity layout
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CB 1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CB 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity class**

```
// Excerpt from the Activity
private TextView targetTextView;
private ViewGroup checkboxContainer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkboxContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_container);
    CheckBox checkbox3 = (CheckBox) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_checkbox, checkboxContainer, false);
    checkbox3.setText("Inflated Checkbox");
    checkboxContainer.addView(checkbox3);
}
```